# Case analysis in Idris proofs

Tags: pattern-matching, proof, idris

So I have wirtten the following type to prove some properties of Integers:

```
data Number : Type where
    PosN : Nat -> Number
    Zero : Number
    NegN : Nat -> Number

plusPosNeg : Nat -> Nat -> Number
plusPosNeg n m with (cmp n m)
    plusPosNeg (k + S d) k  | CmpGT d = PosN d
    plusPosNeg k k          | CmpEQ = Zero
    plusPosNeg k (k + S d)  | CmpLT d = NegN d

plus : Number -> Number -> Number
plus Zero y = y
plus x Zero = x
plus (PosN k) (PosN j) = PosN (k + j)
plus (NegN k) (NegN j) = NegN (k + j)
plus (PosN k) (NegN j) = plusPosNeg k j
plus (NegN k) (PosN j) = plusPosNeg j k
```

Now I'd like to prove that `Zero` is the neutral element of addition, which is quite obvious from the definition of `plus`. And indeed, Idris accepts the following proof:

```
plusRZeroNeutral : {l : Number} -> plus l Zero = l
plusRZeroNeutral {l = Zero} = Refl
plusRZeroNeutral {l = PosN _} = Refl
plusRZeroNeutral {l = NegN _} = Refl
```

But rejects a shorter version I have first come up with:

```
plusRZeroNeutral : {l : Number} -> plus l Zero = l
plusRZeroNeutral {l} = Refl
```

My question is why is that so? Looking at the definition of `plus` it would seem the compiler should know that the constructor passed as right argument to `plus` does not matter as long as the left argument is `Zero` (and vice versa). Perhaps it's a bug, or am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all you know about `l` is that it is, well, `l` (i.e. some arbitrary parameter), then you cannot reduce `plus l Zero` any further since you are stuck on which branch of `plus` to take.

When you pattern match on e.g. `l = Zero`, the right-hand side's type is now refined to `plus Zero Zero = Zero`, which can be reduced (via the definition of `plus`) to `Zero = Zero`. The constructor `Refl`'s type unifies readily with this refined result type, and so the clause `plusRZeroNeutral {l = Zero} = Refl` typechecks.

The other branches are handled similarly by the other clauses of your first definition of `plusRZeroNeutral`.

Comment: Still so, even though there is only one pattern matching `plus l Zero`, whatever that `l` would be? Pitty. Anyway, thanks for explanation.

Comment: But `plus l Zero` can match either the first clause of `plus` (if `l = Zero`) or the second one, since the pattern matching clauses are ordered.

Comment: Ah, I see now! Thank you :)